# Где находится windows.h и как подключить на Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, библиотека

Вообщем такой вопрос, "как поставить библиотеку, чтобы там были заголовки windows.h, conio.h", чтобы они инкудились к примеру в eclipse или просто где ниудь?. как поставить, что скачать, где что брать?

Comment: Вы компилируете из под убунту для... убунту? Если да, то там конечно же не будет хедеров WinAPI. Если кросс-компилируете для виндоус (через mingw), то эти хедеры должны быть в стандартной поставке.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, судя по отсутствующему файлу ```conio.h``` исходной операционной системой все же является Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Проверил способ, о котором говорил @HolyBlackCat - это работает.

[Developing for Windows on Linux](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7128) - основная статья, в ней Вы сможете найти более подробное описание использования mingw-gcc в Linux-based операционной системе. К сожалению, последней под рукой меня нет, я тестировал под Mac'ом.

1. На сайте [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) Вы можете ознакомиться с детальным описанием процесса установки. Для этого перейдите в [Downloads](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) и выберите необходимую операционную систему.
2. После установки перейдите в /usr/local/bin (вероятнее всего) и выполните команду `ls -l | grep mingw`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Найдите версии mingw-gcc для интересующей Вас платформы. С помощью `ln` можете создать ссылку в /usr/bin. Лично я использовал следующую версию: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.
4. На ранее указанном сайте (в конце статьи) Вы можете найти ссылку на архив с исходным кодом для тестирования. Мне пришлось немного его подправить, поэтому здесь я оставлю исправленную версию (см. ниже).
5. Выполните следующую команду: `/usr/local/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o app.exe main.c -mwindows`
6. Исполняемый файл Вы можете запустить либо непосредственно на Win, либо можете использовать [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) чтобы сделать это на текущей машине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Исходный код:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInst,
                   PSTR szCmdLine,
                   int iCmdShow) {
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("HelloWin");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInst;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground =
        (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,
                   TEXT("This program requires Windows NT."), "msg", 0);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
                        TEXT("The Hello Program"),
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInst,
                        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,
                         UINT message,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam) {
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    switch (message) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            DrawText(hdc,
                     TEXT("Hello, Windows!"),
                     -1, &rect,
                     DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем такие сложности?
Вот вариан проще.

```sh
sudo apt install mingw-w64
```